# In bash the command fc does no more write files in /tmp/bash-fc*, why?

Tags: linux, bash

Since about 30 years while working with Linux I am used to have a backup of the files of bash built-in command `fc` in `/tmp/bash-fc*`.

Now these files do not exist more.

I have not found any way to restore the behavior the fc files to be saved as before.

I am using Kubuntu 20.04 and in the moment KNOPPIX 9.1, in detail:

```
uname -a
```

shows

```
Microknoppix 5.10.10-64 #3 SMP PREEMPT Sun Feb 7 09:26:54 CET 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux

/mnt-system/KNOPPIX/kversion
```

shows

```
9.1-2021-01-25
```

Please has someone an idea what is the cause and what can help?

Comment: [Every change breaks someone's workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/). :)

Comment: I have not seen a single system where Bash *wouldn't* immediately remove the 'bash-fc' files as soon as it has executed the command.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to use the `history` instead?

Comment: You have files in /tmp that have been there for 30 years?  Odd, mine get deleted on reboot.  Or did you mean you haven't rebooted in 30 years?  Question is very confusing.